# Run emacs command in terminal

Tags: emacs, osx-elcapitan

I'm using Emacs Muse for work reasons and I don't really enjoy editing my .muse files in emacs.

I haven't found alternatives to publishing .muse files in another editor.

Is it possible to run Emacs commands from outside Emacs almost as if using it as a sort of interpreter?

I want to be able to go to the terminal and run something like:

```
> emacs -ne file_with_command file_to_publish.muse
```

The command in question is `M-x muse-project-publish-this-file`

edit: In Emacs, this command also has inputs that it prompts me to give one at a time. It's the style of publishing (html in my case) and the directory where the publication will go to.

Comment: A wild guess: `emacs file_to_publish.muse -f muse-project-publish-this-file`.

Comment: @legoscia yes that worked well but it then prompted me to give the rest of the inputs of the command. it also opened emacs and I'd rather have the macro run sillently.

Comment: Ah right, I forgot the `--batch` option: `emacs --batch file_to_publish.muse -f muse-project-publish-this-file`. Not sure how to avoid prompting; I don't use Muse.

Answer (score 0):

`muse-project-publish-this-file` is not design to use in batch mode.Use `muse-publish-file` instead.

First,

`git clone https://github.com/jwiegley/muse /path/to/muse`

Then create `script.el` with content

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "/path/to/muse/lisp")
(require 'muse-publish)
(muse-publish-file "file_to_publish.muse" (muse-define-style "newstyle" nil) "/path/to/publish/directory")
```

notice is `/muse/lisp` not `muse`.

Last, `emacs --batch -l script.el`